# How does Kajia's Swarming style work against attacks measured from markers?

Tags: battlecon

For example, say we have the following board setup
S = Kajia Salix
B = Karin Brandtford
**bold** = Jager's marker

oo**S**Booo

Karin has an insect token in each discard pile.

Kajia plays Swarming Drive.
Karin plays Howling Grasp.

Because of the insect tokens opponents at range 1 or 2 cannot hit Kajia. Karin is at range 1 so she should not be able to hit. However, the attack is coming from Jager's position, which is range 0. Does Karin hit in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Howling just calculates range from Jager's position, it doesn't change where Karin is.  Swarming checks Karin's position when determining whether or not you can hit, so the attack misses.